# Azure Data Factory Copy Data From Blob Storage Only New Added file(s)

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I would like to create a pipeline with `Copy Data` (mapping JSON source to MySQL columns). At this moment it is working, but the tool is copying `all the files` from my source container after the `'created' trigger`. Is it possible to retrieve only 'new added' files in my container, so I do not have double data in MySQL?

**Example current situation:**

```
first copy -> retrieve file 1
(added new file)
second copy -> retrieve file 1 + file 2
```

**Example expected situation:**

```
first copy -> retrieve file 1
(added new file)
second copy -> retrieve file 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a very used scenario , you should use LastModifiedDate for copying most recently added files and to prevent duplication.

Please check this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview